# Rsync exclude file that are having same name but different extension

Tags: rsync

Is there any option to send files via rsync that ae having same name but other extension ? For ex filename.ts and filename.mp4 ??

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. The question title says you want to *exclude* files with the same base name, but the text says you want to *send* them. If filename.ts and filename.mp4 both exist, do you want to send both of them, just one of them, or neither of them? What if there are three or more files with the same base name? In any case, I suspect the answer is that `rsync` can't do it by rule, you need to prescan the directory and build include/exclude lists.

Answer (score 0):

I`m havin for example filename.ts on destination and filename.mp4 on source. I dont want to send filename .mp to destination becase basename is the same.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, and should be included as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55211871/edit) instead.